# Are there cerifications needed to bring 5VDC LED Controller to the US market?

Tags: led, controller

We are producing LED programmable controler, the power supply is 5VDC.
Do we need any certification (UL or similar) for the US market?

Comment: Have you read: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297060/at-what-level-of-complexity-should-i-consider-ul-listing-my-widget/297085#297085 ? Please make clear what your product involves because your title suggests that the power supply is included (so you do mains in => 5 V DC out) but in the text you act like the 5 V DC needs to be supplied from elsewhere. Having a product that is mains connected or not makes a **huge difference**.

Comment: A programmable controller will almost certainly contain digital doings at above 9kHz, so will very likely need FCC approval at the least even if it is all SELV.